# Vue pie chart show after a while (like show console with a warning)

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, pie-chart

I am trying to fill a pie chart on my vue application, I can correctly fill data into it, but the page didn't show immediately the pie chart, but after a while (like if a show console), and I got a warning in console :

> vue.esm.js?efeb:628 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for
>   prop "chartData". Expected Object, got Null
>
> found in
>
> ---> 
>           at src/components/StastCard.vue
>               at src/App.vue

Here my code (Maybe there was another way to fill data, but I only succesfully done it in this way):
StastCard.vue:

```
<template>
<div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <pie-chart :chartData="dataChart"></pie-chart>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import DataService from '@/services/DataService'
import PieChart from "@/plugins/PieChart.js";
export default {
  name: 'StastCard',
  props: {
    username: {
        type: String
    }
  },
  components: {
      PieChart
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      dataChart: {
        labels: ["Km", "KJ", "HB"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Data One",
            backgroundColor: ["#41B883", "#E46651", "#00D8FF"],
            data: [1, 10, 5]
          }
        ]
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async addData() {
      this.firstValue=DataService.getFirstValue()
      this.secondValue=DataService.getSecondValue()
      this.thirdValue=DataService.getThirdValue()

      this.dataChart.labels.pop()
      this.dataChart.labels.pop()
      this.dataChart.labels.pop()
      this.dataChart.labels.push(["Km"])
      this.dataChart.labels.push(["KJ"])
      this.dataChart.labels.push(["HB"])
      this.dataChart.datasets[0].data.pop()
      this.dataChart.datasets[0].data.pop()
      this.dataChart.datasets[0].data.pop()
      this.dataChart.datasets[0].data.push(this.firstValue)
      this.dataChart.datasets[0].data.push(this.secondValue)
      this.dataChart.datasets[0].data.push(this.thirdValue)
   },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.addData()
  }
}

</script>
```

And here my PieChart.js

```
import { Pie, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
export default {
  extends: Pie,
  props: ['chartData', 'options'],
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why my pie chart is not immediately displayed? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, I change the .js file with this:

```
import { Pie } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Pie,
  props: {
    chartdata: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    renderpie() {
      this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
    }
  },
  mounted() {}
}
```

Here my view:

```
<template>
<div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <pie-chart :chartData="dataChart"></pie-chart>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import DataService from '@/services/DataService'
import PieChart from "@/plugins/PieChart.js";
export default {
  name: 'StastCard',
  props: {
    username: {
        type: String
    }
  },
  components: {
      PieChart
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      dataChart: {},
      firstValue:'',
      secondValue:'',
      thirdValue:''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addData() {
      this.firstValue=DataService.getFirstValue()
      this.secondValue=DataService.getSecondValue()
      this.thirdValue=DataService.getThirdValue()
      var hrate = []
      this.heart_rate.forEach(el => {
        hrate.push(el.rate)
      })
      this.dataChart = {
        labels: ['Km', 'Kj', 'HB'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Data One',
            backgroundColor: ['#41B883', '#E46651', '#00D8FF'],
            data: [this.firstValue,this.secondValue,this.thirdValue]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  },
  async created() {
    await this.addData()
    this.$refs.pie.renderpie()
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you might want to use `reactiveProp` to make your chart reactive with data changes.

Secondly, because of vue-chartjs will render child component before parent component, so you will get the  Invalid prop warning. To fix it, you can change from mounted to created hook. You can find more information [here](https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f).

```
import { Pie, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
export default {
  extends: Pie,
  mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
  created() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, {})
  }
}
```

Lastly, you should assign chartData object to a new reference to make Vue reactive. An easy way is using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`

```
  methods: {
    async addData() {
      this.firstValue=DataService.getFirstValue()
      this.secondValue=DataService.getSecondValue()
      this.thirdValue=DataService.getThirdValue()

      this.dataChart.labels.pop()
      this.dataChart.labels.pop()
      this.dataChart.labels.pop()
      this.dataChart.labels.push(["Km"])
      this.dataChart.labels.push(["KJ"])
      this.dataChart.labels.push(["HB"])
      this.dataChart.datasets[0].data.pop()
      this.dataChart.datasets[0].data.pop()
      this.dataChart.datasets[0].data.pop()
      this.dataChart.datasets[0].data.push(this.firstValue)
      this.dataChart.datasets[0].data.push(this.secondValue)
      this.dataChart.datasets[0].data.push(this.thirdValue)
      this.dataChart = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dataChart))
   },
  },
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but nothing that you can write work, maybe it's my fault because I'm not very good with Vue,but If I change the .js with yours I got the same warning as before, another warning and an error, the new warning is : 
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined"

found in
the error is : vue.esm.js?efeb:1897 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined
    at VueComponent.renderChart (BaseCharts.js?a889:61)
    at VueComponent.created (PieChart.js?408a:7)

Comment: and If i use  this.dataChart = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dataChart)) I get: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'datasets' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     ...
    |     property 'config' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'data' closes the circle
    at Object.stringify (<anonymous>)